# Angular js http get return all page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Why `console.log(response.data);` in http get, returns html of all page, but not the value of `returnUrl`('Home/Index').

I think that the problem is in `await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);`.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Login(string UserName, string Password, bool RememberMe, string returnUrl)
    {
        LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel();
        model.Password = Password;
        model.UserName = UserName;
        model.RememberMe = RememberMe;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password); if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.ConfirmedEmail == true)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return Json(returnUrl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Confirm Email Address.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Json(returnUrl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.answer = function (answer) {
$scope.returnUrl = '/Home/Index';  
$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/Account/Login',
      params: {
      UserName: $scope.model.UserName,
      Password: $scope.model.Password,
      RememberMe: $scope.model.RememberMe,
      returnUrl: $scope.returnUrl
      }
      }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      }, function () {
           console.log("Error occured");
      });
```

html response

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>About - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/Custom/Login.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/angular-messages.js"></script>


    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.0.8/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><div ng-app="LoginApp" ng-controller="LoginCtrl"><input type="button" value="Login" ng-click="showAdvanced($event)" /></div></li>
                </ul>
                <form action="/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="78GcsaZMHozpxPWZojKt_U4oOlCC91bdiNLnrM9bnGkHAwTdludG--qpyQSGXaurmBHnyYUiIlGpNsGfkskwnMHyc_BozsM2pdl4IWBoWos27DcNf3c57PLPRcmNBm-INZRgLICtO1PG4DcOWJRm6yj6Sr_kSDElCuPf-H8AD2BACTChafGXEic38UObx3PdnTDg-C6Iah7AyhjZvagKlw2" />        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="/Account/Manage" title="Manage">Hello Anton!</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
        </ul>
</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">


<h2>About</h2>

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2016 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/bundles/bootstrap"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `/Home/Index` not the action that would return your complete page?

Comment: @HuguesStefanski, But i thought that it should return only string '/Home/Index'.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code,
If login success it will return a **json** with returnUrl.

But if login fail it will return an **html** document with error messages.

So the reason you are getting back HTML is because you probably have error in login process.

Comment: Can you share result html?

Comment: I found where is problem. Sometimes Controller return only returns variable which contains only (/'Home/Index'), sometimes it returns object which have many different properties and one of them is html page.